# spring boot kafka consumer id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot with kafka. Is it possible to get number of kafka consumer threads and consumer id at the app startup?
I tried with below kafka client admin code but its giving null pointer exception with given groupid.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61616543Application {

    @Autowired
    KafkaClient adminClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61616543Application.class, args);
        log.info(members().toString());
    }

    public Collection<MemberDescription> members() 
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException 
    {
       String group = "my-consumer";
       List<String> groups = Collections.singletonList(group);

       return adminClient
         .describeConsumerGroups(groups) // DescribeConsumerGroupsResult
         .describedGroups()              
         //Map<String,KafkaFuture<ConsumerGroupDescription>>
         .get(group)                     // KafkaFuture<ConsumerGroupDescription>
         .get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)       // ConsumerGroupDescription
         .members();                     // Collection<MemberDescription>
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

How does it work if you remove that `close()` for Spring application context ? You cannot have consumer after closing context, so that’s not a surprise to see an NPE at that point.

Comment: I tried removing close. Still the same NPE. I updated my question.